# Python Dataframe list of lists of dataframes into a single dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a big list consisting of 39 sublists. Each sublist has many dataframes. Now, I want to convert them into a single dataframe.

[image]

My code:

```
append_data = [[Dataframe,...][Dataframe,...]]
combined_csv = pd.concat(append_data)
```

Present output:

```
    raise TypeError(msg)

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'list'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two `concat`

```
pd.concat(pd.concat(x) for  x in append_data )
```